# Spring Boot security getting Bad credentials error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am new to Spring Boot Security and try to implement JWT based authentication & authorisation.  I have made all the required setup configuration for spring security. Even with right credentials, from Spring Security I am getting error - Bad Credential.
I have hard coded the user details which need to be supplied for spring security (No database call).

My code is like below,

SpringConfig.java

```java
package com.wocs.rest.controller;

//import com.example.polls.security.CustomUserDetailsService;
//import com.example.polls.security.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
//import com.example.polls.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.BeanIds;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.wocs.rest.security.CustomUserDetailsService;
import com.wocs.rest.security.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import com.wocs.rest.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter;


/**
 * Created by rajeevkumarsingh on 01/08/17.
 */

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                    .and()
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                    .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                        .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/auth/login")
                        .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated();

        // Add our custom JWT security filter
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
}
```

CustomUserDetailsService.java

```java
package com.wocs.rest.security;

import com.wocs.services.user.iface.UserServiceIface;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

/**
 * Created by rajeevkumarsingh on 02/08/17.
 */

@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceIface userService;

    public void setUserService(UserServiceIface userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String loginIDorPhoneOrEmail)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // Let people login with either loginID or email or Phone       
        //User user = new User();
        //UserPassword userPassword = new UserPassword();
        List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
        permissions.add("P1");
        permissions.add("P2");
        permissions.add("P3");
        UserDetails userDetails =  UserPrincipal.create(115, loginIDorPhoneOrEmail,"222",true, permissions);
        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

JWTAuthenticationEntryPoint.java

```java
package com.wocs.rest.security;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by rajeevkumarsingh on 07/12/17.
 */
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint.class);
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                         HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                         AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.error("Responding with unauthorized error. Message - {}", e.getMessage());
        httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                "Sorry, You're not authorized to access this resource.");
    }
}
```

UserPrincipal.java

```java
package com.wocs.rest.security;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class UserPrincipal implements UserDetails {
    private int id;

    private String username;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    private boolean isCredentialNonExpired = false;

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public UserPrincipal(int id, String username, String password, boolean isCredentialNonExpired, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.authorities = authorities;
        this.isCredentialNonExpired = isCredentialNonExpired;
    }

    public static UserPrincipal create(int userID, String userName, String password,boolean isCredentialNonExpired, List<String> permissions) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = permissions.stream().map(permission ->
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority(permission)
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new UserPrincipal(
                userID,
                userName,
                password,
                isCredentialNonExpired,
                authorities
        );
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return isCredentialNonExpired;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        UserPrincipal that = (UserPrincipal) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, that.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

AuthController.java

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "text/plain")
public Map login(@RequestBody String stringRequestBody) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException, ServiceException
{
    logger.info("Auth JSON Request:" + stringRequestBody);
    Map<String, String> jsonMap = parseJSON(stringRequestBody);
    String username = "rahul@gmail.com";
    String password = "222";

    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,password)
    );
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    String jwt = tokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);
    User user = userService.getUserByLoginIDOrPhoneOrEmail(username);
    Map userDetail = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    if (user != null) {
        userDetail.put("user", user);
        userDetail.put("userType", userService.getUserTypeByUserID(user.getID()));
        userDetail.put("permissions", userService.getUserPermissions(user.getID()));
        userDetail.put("token", jwt);
    }
   return userDetail;   
}
```

I am trying to hit the api, but its throwing me:

```
{
 "timestamp":"2018-08-08T08:42:14.575+0000",
 "status":401,
 "error":"Unauthorized",
 "message":"Sorry, You're not authorized to access this resource.",
 "path":"/auth/login"
}
```

Log error - `Responding with unauthorized error. Message - Bad credentials`

I had referred below link for spring security implementation
https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-spring-security-jwt-mysql-react-app-part-2/

Please Help me.

Comment: What version of Spring Security are you using? If you are using Spring Security 5+ remember that the default PasswordEncoder is PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder(). You can either encode your password using the default PasswordEncoder, for testing you can prefix it with "{noop}", or you can expose a NoOpPasswordEncoder as a Bean. The first solution is the only thing that is acceptable for production as the 2nd and third solutions are not secure.

Comment: Yes I have spring security version 5.0.3 ... could you please elaborate more?..